# Javascript - Split string by first 2 white spaces

Tags: javascript

I have a string, which contains multiple white spaces. 
I want to split it by only first 2 white spaces.

```
224 Brandywine Court Fairfield, CA 94533
```

output

```
["224", "Brandywine", "Court Fairfield, CA 94533"]
```

Comment: `.match(/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.+)/).slice(1)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const str ="224 Brandywine Court Fairfield, CA 94533";
const arr = str.split(" ");
const array = arr.slice(0, 2).concat(arr.slice(2).join(" "));

console.log(array);
```

You can do it with split and slice functions.

- [Array​.prototype​.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
- [String​.prototype​.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: But I got only ["224", "Brandywine"] ?

Comment: This **does not** do what the OP wants. It will only give you the first two items

Comment: This also does not give desired result.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I might do it.

```js
const s = "224 Brandywine Court Fairfield, CA 94533";

function splitFirst(s, by, n = 1){
  const splat = s.split(by);
  const first = splat.slice(0,n);
  const last = splat.slice(n).join(by);
  if(last) return [...first, last];
  return first;
}
console.log(splitFirst(s, " ", 2));
```

Comment: Your code works but I just want to see if there is a shorter way to achieve it. Still many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about the space character (and not tabs or other whitespace characters) and only care about everything before the second space and everything after the second space, you can do it:

```
let str = `224 Brandywine Court Fairfield, CA 94533`;
let firstWords = str.split(' ', 2);
let otherWords = str.substring(str.indexOf(' ', str.indexOf(' ') + 1));
let result = [...firstWords, otherWords];
```

Comment: Your code gives me back : [ "224", "Brandywine", "randywine Court Fairfield CA 94533" ]